# Is it possible to add parent to child for ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-polymorphic

Say I have a ForeignKey field called "parent" with a related_name of "children":

```
class Item(PolymorphicModel):
    title = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", related_name='children', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Parent(Item):
    pass

class Child(Item):
    pass
```

Why is it that I can only add the child to the parent but I get an error if I try to add a parent to the child?

So this works:

```
p1 = Parent.objects.create(title="Parent 1")
c1 = Child.objects.create(title="Child 1")

print(p1.children)
#<PolymorphicQuerySet []>

p1.children.add(c1)
```

But this doesn't:

```
p1 = Parent.objects.create(title="Parent 1")
c1 = Child.objects.create(title="Child 1")
print(c1.parent)
# None

c1.parent.add(p1)
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Do I just have to add to the Parent's children field each time? Is there no way to add to the Child's parent instead? Is there any reason why adding to the Child's parent doesn't work or shouldn't be used?

I'm also a little confused about when/how to use "_set" in this circumstance (if that's relevant). So following the format of [Django's Many-to-one example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), the following doesn't work for me either:

```
p1 = Parent.objects.create(title="Parent 1")
c1 = Child.objects.create(title="Child 1")
p1.children.add(c1)

print(p1.children_set.all())
# AttributeError: 'p1' object has no attribute 'children_set'

print(c1.parent_set.all())
# AttributeError: 'c1' object has no attribute 'parent_set'

print(p1.item_set.all())
# AttributeError: 'p1' object has no attribute 'item_set'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you are confusing yourself here with `parent` and `child` naming here.  The `related_name` field in `ForeignKey` essentially tells the model to set up a relationship to quickly find all related instances of the model with the given `ForeignKey`.  When you call `p1.children`, you are getting the correct output because there are no related instances to `p1`.  You similarly get the correct output when you call `c1.parent` and get `None`.  The line that I copied and pasted below is what causes this.  By setting `null=True`, you are saying to instantiate the `Item` instance (whether it's `Parent` or `Child`), with a null `parent` field (in python, null is `None`).

Your perceived problem comes when you call `c1.parent.add()`.  Since you have not set `parent` to anything, its value is `None`, and it likewise does not have an `add()` method.  What you should be doing is setting `parent=[some instance of Parent]`.  Then, when you want to get the `children` of a given `Parent` instance, let's say `p1`, you can call `p1.children`, and you will get a queryset full of `Child` instances whose `parent` field has been set to the foreign key of that `Parent` instance.

```
parent = models.ForeignKey(
    "self", related_name='children', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```